# TFS API, determining differences programmatically

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk

**Question background:**

I'm currently comparing specified file differences between two different branch folders. For example the following works perfectly:

```
        var potentialDifference = Difference.DiffFiles(locationPathA, FileType.Detect(locationPathA, null), locationPathB, FileType.Detect(locationPathB, null), new DiffOptions());

        string result = potentialDifference.Next == null ? "Identical" : "Different";

        Assert.IsNotNull(result);

        Assert.AreSame(result, "Identical");
```

**The actual question:**

What I need to know is do I need to download both the workspaces of the branch folders from TFS and do the comparison between the respective workspaces?

Comment: @jessehouwing Have I tried the above code? Yes, it works perfectly. What I need to know is when comparing files in TFS folders, do I have to download the folder branches to a workspace to compare them?

Comment: Again, have you tried doing the comparison without downloading them? It's the simplest way to find out.